# How to check server for SSLv3 connection if there isn't any openssl package on it?

Tags: openssl

```
echo Q | openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect HOSTNAME:PORT 2>/dev/null | grep 'Cipher is'
```

But how can I test for SSLv3 connection if there isn't any openssl installed on the machine?

UPDATE: the machine isn't internet faced

Comment: You do it using 3rd party? https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

Comment: Many thanks, good idea :) but not all the machines facing the internet

Answer (score 2):

If `nmap` is available on your system. Assuming you will be checking for SSLv3 against port 443, you can use `nmap` with the following options:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers  -p 443 <hostname/IP>  | grep SSLv3
```

If the `grep` returns nothing it means SSLv3 protocol is disabled, if it returns something (it will return the protocols supported and the ciphers used) it means SSLv3 is still enabled on the target host.

Check [this](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html) to see what ssl-enum-ciphers does.

If SSLv3 i

Comment: I would have dropped the pipe to grep! Then you will get all ciphers which SSLv3 is using. Also checking the ciphers of the TLS protocols.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend  [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/), you may have one or both available already:

```
wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3 https://zmap.io/
curl --sslv3 https://zmap.io/
```

or otherwise [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/):

```
socat stdio openssl-connect:zmap.io:443,method=sslv3
```

`socat` requires OpenSSL's libssl and libcrypto for SSL support, `wget` and `curl` require either OpenSSL or GnuTLS. zmap.io is a security related site that has SSLv3 disabled,

Otherwise, in a pinch you can do this with `bash` (and a little suspension of disbelief).
Take a minimal SSlv3 "client hello", and write it in binary to a file:

```
( echo 16 03 00 00 49
  echo 01 00 00 45 03 00 54 46 2c 8b a0 70 ac c5 9f 96
  echo 60 b9 d0 97 af a5 95 c4 41 3b fa 49 dc cd eb 63
  echo df df cf 66 95 29 00 00 1e 00 39 00 38 00 35 00
  echo 16 00 13 00 0a 00 33 00 32 00 2f 00 05 00 04 00
  echo 15 00 12 00 09 00 ff 01 00 ) | xxd -r -p > ssl3.bin
```

Then it's as simple (!) as:

```
$ exec 4<> /dev/tcp/zmap.io/443
$ cat ssl3.bin >&4
$ hexdump -C <&4
00000000  15 03 00 00 02 02 28                              |......(|
```

The important bytes here are the leading 0x15 (SSL Alert record) and 0x28, handshake failure. If the connection worked you should instead get back a first byte of 0x16 (SSL Handshake record) and a large chunk containing a certificate, and more. You can use any hostname or IP address here, i.e. `/dev/tcp/hostname/port/`.

You can create your own handshake using the following method from another machine with OpenSSL's `s_client`.

```
echo Q | openssl s_client -ssl3 -msg -debug -cipher 'DEFAULT:!EXPORT' \
   -connect www.google.com:443 >debug.log
```

The main requirement is that you `connect` to a host that will accept a connection. There is no [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) here, so the payload we capture can be used to test any server (though a server could reject the connection if strict SNI was enforced, SNI isn't defined for SSlv3).

```
$ head -15 debug.log
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x80c6ed0 [0x80d0c88] (78 bytes => 78 (0x4E))
0000 - 16 03 00 00 49 01 00 00-45 03 00 54 46 2c 8b a0   ....I...E..TF,..
[...]
>>> SSL 3.0 Handshake [length 0049], ClientHello
    01 00 00 45 03 00 54 46 2c 8b a0 70 ac c5 9f 96
    60 b9 d0 97 af a5 95 c4 41 3b fa 49 dc cd eb 63
    df df cf 66 95 29 00 00 1e 00 39 00 38 00 35 00
    16 00 13 00 0a 00 33 00 32 00 2f 00 05 00 04 00
    15 00 12 00 09 00 ff 01 00
read from 0x80c6ed0 [0x80cc478] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
```

(The output with `-msg` instead of `-debug` is neater, but it omits the leading 5 byte of the SSL record, and `-debug` unhelpfully chops off important trailing 0 bytes, so we need to use both.)

Take the leading 5 bytes of hex on the line starting with 0000 (this is the SSL record header that the next hex chunk omits), and then take the entire hex chunk after the line "SSL 3.0 Handshake", and convert the lot to a binary file using `xxd` as above.

The only variable here is that the leading 4 bytes of the random (octets 11-14 of the record) will be the client timestamp. This could be detected by a sufficiently paranoid server, but in SSLv3 [the client clock is not required to be correct](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101#section-5.6.1.2) (not even in versions up to and including TLS 1.2).

You can read the more about [SSL record format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101#section-5.2) here, and here for the [registered ciphers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml).